# vertically center page around a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know vertical center in CSS is a pain to begin with, but I've just made it a bit more complicated. On my page, I have:

```
<ul id="complete">
</ul>

<form id="new_item_form">
  <input type="text" id="add_item" placeholder="Type some tasks here"/>
</form>

<ul id="incomplete">
</ul>
```

It's for a basic task list. Tasks are added to the incomplete ul, and when completed move to the complete ul. What I want to do via css is have the text field vertically centered on the page and stay there, with the two lists butted up against it. I've been looking at all sorts of vertical alignment (a summary of forms found here: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/ ) but I can't seem to find a way that I can figure out how to adapt to allow what I need. How would I accomplish this style of fixed position centering?

EDIT:
Here's an image of what I'm looking for: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i0oit3v84j93b5g/Screen%20Shot%202012-10-11%20at%204.27.16%20PM.png

Comment: You list JavaScript and jQuery -- please specify if you are looking for a CSS solution (hard) or a jQuery solution (easy).

Comment: I'm looking for a CSS solution, but if there were a solid argument for using jQuery to do this (considering the entire to-do list is run with jQuery) I'd be open to that solution. I'm not sure which is the "right" or "better" way of doing it.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "butted up against"? It seems like you want the entire block (uls and forms) to be vertically centered. An MS paint sketch would really help.

Comment: I've added a sketch. The page is focused around the vertically-centered text field. Both ul's grow in length away from the text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any way to do this with CSS, but it's fairly easy to do with JavaScript/jQuery.  Here is a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q68L/1/) that does what you want on document load.  You'd call the code again if you changed the lists, of course.

First, you enclose your lists and form in a div.  I called this id="cmiddle".  Then you use CSS to set the cmiddle div as position: relative.  Then you use JavaScript code to get the enclosing window or frame height, calculate the center for the form, and then, subtract the upper list height to get the correct div position:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    // To work with frames, too
    function getParentDocHeight($ele) {
        for (;;) {
            if (!$ele || !$ele.length) {
                return $(window).height();
            }
            $ele = $ele.parent();
            if ($ele.is("frame") || $ele.is("window")) {
                return $ele.height();
            }
        }
    }
    var $cm = $("#cmiddle");
    var formHeight = $("#new_item_form").outerHeight();
    var viewHeight = getParentDocHeight($cm)
    var formTop = (viewHeight - formHeight) / 2;
    var divTop = formTop - $("#complete").outerHeight();
    $cm.css("top", divTop);
});
```

**Edit**: Kraz was nice enough to add a simulation of adding list items to both lists and calling the code again to recalc.  His [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6q68L/3/).

Comment: This solution is as elegant as I think this is going to get. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget you'll have to recalculate your height with each tasks you'll add! [I've updated the jsfiddle accordingly](http://jsfiddle.net/6q68L/3/).

Comment: @Kraz, thanks.  I did mention to call the code again if the lists changed but your demo is quite nice.

Answer (score 2):

[Is this what you want to obtain](http://jsfiddle.net/Xz8Zg/2/)?

Of course, my code is a bit sketchy (use of height attribute on tds! Don't scold me *to much*). But you get the point.

If the height of the table is not known nor fix, but its parent height is known, it won't work ([see this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Xz8Zg/1/)) and you'll have to break it down.

If you just don't know any height at all, it's kind of hard to align...

[Further reading on vertical-align](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html)

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm trying to get to! But I'm supposed to feel bad about myself if I use tables, aren't I?

Comment: There's a table less solution in my _further reading_ link, using absolute positioning. You should avoid using table for layout, but when you can't find anything else...

Comment: Yeah. The problem with these though is that you need to know the height of the page. I think this would be a great solution if I knew the height. I'm going to go with the jQuery

Comment: There's a lot of valuable info here, even if it didn't completely satisfy the OP's needs.  +1.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure what you are talking about

But generally,
put the line-height = the div's height. I will create a div around it if necessary

if some very particular situations, i do some math to manually center it

So if you want to centering 1 thing, create a div go around it with line-height = the div's height
And then make the div position: absolute, width, height, ....

Hope this helps